# how to centralize bubble in faced grid

Tags: r, bubble-chart

I need help distributing the bubbles within each facet grid and removing the grid lines inside each facet grid in the graphic below.

```
graph <- ggplot(patog1, aes(x = Prevalence, y = Microorganism)) +
  geom_point(data=patog1,aes(x=JitCoOr, y=JitCoOrPow,size = Samples, colour = Study), alpha=.5)+
  geom_text(data=patog1,aes(x=JitCoOr, y=JitCoOrPow,label=Samples)) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1,30))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(10))+ 
  facet_grid(Microorganism~.)+
  theme_bw()
graph

graph + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
             axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

I also would like to have the name of the Microorganisms  - the faced  in the left side.

Here is my dataframe

```r
> dput(head(patog1, 20))
structure(list(Microorganism = c("Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", 
"Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", 
"Staphylococci aureus"), Prevalence = c(23.9, 58.2, 9.3, 56, 
56, 45, 23.2, 55.7, 56.4, 15.3, 44, 38.9, 34.5, 1.6, 4.3, 10.3, 
3.9, 10, 8, 0.4), Samples = c(307, 424, 165, 150, 152, 59, 72, 
173, 191, 1077, 200, 185, 808, 307, 424, 165, 290, 59, 661, 1077
), Study = c("1", "3", "4", "6", "17", "10", "11", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "20", "18", "1", "3", "4", "9", "10", "12", "15"), 
    radius = c(2.75818894925504, 4.30414165379076, 1.72054698904426, 
    4.22200824564475, 4.22200824564475, 3.78469878303024, 2.7174968922639, 
    4.21068410836495, 4.23706001618643, 2.20683965403289, 3.74241031850956, 
    3.5188427888369, 3.31386346630949, 0.713649646461108, 1.16992842113964, 
    1.81068821935005, 1.11418515342684, 1.78412411615277, 1.59576912160573, 
    0.356824823230554), JitCoOr = c(52.9537293797359, 62.0532565008849, 
    39.0785944228992, 59.9366020258516, 60.044047411345, 56.9612927732058, 
    51.9691243943758, 58.8738514398225, 60.8206247391179, 47.8702185059898, 
    56.0192426254973, 55.199258433003, 54.0486559784971, 5.81677224850282, 
    21.9080965784378, 42.9893445299938, 19.90970782144, 42.1101505364291, 
    36.0588588385843, 0.817146013118327), JitCoOrPow = c(9.03914307709783, 
    9.00067050699145, 9.1362363233231, 8.83267976436764, 9.05750821055844, 
    9.07773876339197, 9.19675751486793, 8.87710817120969, 8.98355117850006, 
    8.83994870837778, 8.99074420211837, 9.14479981157929, 8.90359472669661, 
    7.87938763340935, 7.89290500981733, 8.15278417477384, 8.00291525470093, 
    8.13870471678674, 7.93727878862992, 7.83678827155381)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> dput(head(patog1, 100))
structure(list(Microorganism = c("Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci coagulase negative", "Staphylococci coagulase negative", 
"Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", 
"Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", 
"Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", "Staphylococci aureus", 
"Staphylococci aureus", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", 
"Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Klebsiella pneumoniae", 
"Klebsiella pneumoniae", "Escherichia coli", "Escherichia coli", 
"Escherichia coli", "Escherichia coli", "Escherichia coli", "Escherichia coli", 
"Escherichia coli", "Escherichia coli", "Escherichia coli", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", 
"Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", 
"Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Acinetobacter baumanni", 
"Acinetobacter baumanni", "Acinetobacter baumanni", "Acinetobacter baumanni", 
"Acinetobacter baumanni", "Acinetobacter baumanni", "Enterobacter spp", 
"Enterobacter spp", "Enterobacter spp", "Enterobacter spp", "Enterococcus spp", 
"Enterococcus spp", "Enterococcus spp", "Enterococcus spp", "Enterococcus spp", 
"Enterococcus spp", "Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", 
"Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", 
"Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal", "Fungal"), Prevalence = c(23.9, 
58.2, 9.3, 56, 56, 45, 23.2, 55.7, 56.4, 15.3, 44, 38.9, 34.5, 
1.6, 4.3, 10.3, 3.9, 10, 8, 0.4, 7.2, 3.7, 2.4, 2.9, 15, 5, 4.1, 
2, 7.6, 6.5, 7.7, 9.6, 16.8, 22, 10, 1.7, 2, 4.5, 6.5, 4.9, 15, 
3, 1.5, 5.3, 3.2, 0.9, 1, 7.1, 2, 4.7, 7, 2.1, 1, 1.8, 5.9, 5, 
12, 22.4, 3.9, 3.78, 11.4, 0.86, 5.8, 3.6, 3.1, 48, 3.7, 8.6, 
5, 15, 2.6, 14.4, 8.1, 1.7, 2.1, 9.9), Samples = c(307, 424, 
165, 150, 152, 59, 72, 173, 191, 1077, 200, 185, 808, 307, 424, 
165, 290, 59, 661, 1077, 152, 185, 808, 290, 59, 661, 1077, 152, 
808, 307, 424, 165, 290, 661, 173, 1077, 152, 808, 307, 290, 
59, 661, 1077, 808, 307, 290, 661, 1077, 152, 808, 661, 1077, 
152, 808, 290, 59, 661, 1077, 808, 185, 307, 1273, 424, 165, 
397, 150, 214, 70, 59, 661, 191, 1077, 808, 474, 185, 290), Study = c("1", 
"3", "4", "6", "17", "10", "11", "13", "14", "15", "16", "20", 
"18", "1", "3", "4", "9", "10", "12", "15", "17", "29", "18", 
"9", "10", "12", "15", "17", "18", "1", "3", "4", "9", "12", 
"13", "15", "17", "18", "1", "9", "10", "12", "15", "18", "1", 
"9", "12", "15", "17", "18", "12", "15", "17", "18", "9", "10", 
"12", "15", "18", "20", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"10", "12", "14", "15", "18", "21", "20", "9"), radius = c(2.75818894925504, 
4.30414165379076, 1.72054698904426, 4.22200824564475, 4.22200824564475, 
3.78469878303024, 2.7174968922639, 4.21068410836495, 4.23706001618643, 
2.20683965403289, 3.74241031850956, 3.5188427888369, 3.31386346630949, 
0.713649646461108, 1.16992842113964, 1.81068821935005, 1.11418515342684, 
1.78412411615277, 1.59576912160573, 0.356824823230554, 1.5138795132121, 
1.08524033231355, 0.874038744473663, 0.960780240186585, 2.18509686118416, 
1.26156626101008, 1.14239683707263, 0.797884560802865, 1.55536334500875, 
1.4384068479379, 1.5655625581928, 1.74807748894733, 2.31248915411244, 
2.64628371420061, 1.78412411615277, 0.735613218010963, 0.797884560802865, 
1.1968268412043, 1.4384068479379, 1.24888688130694, 2.18509686118416, 
0.97720502380584, 0.690988298942671, 1.29886196217077, 1.00925300880806, 
0.535237234845831, 0.564189583547756, 1.50332970166391, 0.797884560802865, 
1.22313387045892, 1.49270533036046, 0.817588381146626, 0.564189583547756, 
0.756939756606048, 1.37041173684567, 1.26156626101008, 1.95441004761168, 
2.67023247124982, 1.11418515342684, 1.09690991871472, 1.90492327994993, 
0.523207895695449, 1.35874844613195, 1.07047446969166, 0.993358267278101, 
3.90882009522336, 1.08524033231355, 1.65452864018143, 1.26156626101008, 
2.18509686118416, 0.909728368293446, 2.14094893938333, 1.60571170453749, 
0.735613218010963, 0.817588381146626, 1.77518108181096), JitCoOr = c(52.9537293797359, 
62.0532565008849, 39.0785944228992, 59.9366020258516, 60.044047411345, 
56.9612927732058, 51.9691243943758, 58.8738514398225, 60.8206247391179, 
47.8702185059898, 56.0192426254973, 55.199258433003, 54.0486559784971, 
5.81677224850282, 21.9080965784378, 42.9893445299938, 19.90970782144, 
42.1101505364291, 36.0588588385843, 0.817146013118327, 33.0946799211204, 
17.9733058359474, 10.9837412635796, 13.1981137231924, 46.8427434850484, 
25.8778913124464, 21.0825900368392, 8.82317104134709, 33.9438152883202, 
30.1352072700858, 34.9239843650721, 40.019158882089, 49.1305902745575, 
50.1613460198045, 42.1171545682475, 6.91049184789881, 9.04398515755311, 
22.9568010552786, 30.0390831185505, 24.844200709369, 47.1902362979949, 
13.9909223258495, 5.12252249410376, 26.8357132209465, 16.1405700452626, 
2.98700527055189, 3.95436205444857, 31.8687793305144, 9.10231541376561, 
23.8016606531106, 30.8522547448985, 10.0403863609768, 3.96650114795193, 
8.12822173433378, 29.0722099646926, 26.0967087958008, 44.9233711795881, 
50.8655211300589, 20.1719161574729, 19.0288566277362, 43.9595239535905, 
1.81553317187354, 27.9933262486011, 17.151779101789, 14.8274631401524, 
57.9104666036554, 17.9814745260403, 37.9474771942943, 26.0181835262105, 
46.9132438350469, 11.9454135867767, 45.8337836777791, 37.0391653109342, 
6.89612202439457, 9.85659030899405, 41.1932372558862), JitCoOrPow = c(9.03914307709783, 
9.00067050699145, 9.1362363233231, 8.83267976436764, 9.05750821055844, 
9.07773876339197, 9.19675751486793, 8.87710817120969, 8.98355117850006, 
8.83994870837778, 8.99074420211837, 9.14479981157929, 8.90359472669661, 
7.87938763340935, 7.89290500981733, 8.15278417477384, 8.00291525470093, 
8.13870471678674, 7.93727878862992, 7.83678827155381, 8.0910329354927, 
8.12914157127961, 7.80564800221473, 6.13817321993411, 5.90554165812209, 
5.82447278564796, 5.95850338637829, 5.84010715493932, 5.97392952665687, 
4.16093768849969, 3.86766330143437, 4.12012600041926, 4.07185018146411, 
4.04207222368568, 3.91818653987721, 3.88875154945999, 4.10133589757606, 
4.04486549412832, 7.08866870719939, 7.1921757302247, 7.09146734382957, 
6.84114244831726, 7.1966904586181, 6.90712704788893, 1.14620719207451, 
0.880739877559245, 0.83798291767016, 1.08403717856854, 0.876667608134449, 
1.06033392539248, 1.95018634768203, 1.90881395954639, 2.05503583196551, 
2.00373990433291, 3.04555658176541, 2.84971538251266, 3.0246863745153, 
3.17671390501782, 3.10960682872683, 2.81259256033227, 4.99736648378894, 
5.17767235841602, 4.97637547263876, 4.90573497125879, 4.84745719758794, 
5.02040644623339, 4.90035738507286, 5.14835271695629, 4.84300309810787, 
4.97609931230545, 4.96553065059707, 5.02887920197099, 5.17221848322079, 
5.07821689154953, 5.17920738002285, 5.10063524739817)), row.names = c(NA, 
-76L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: my graph after the help]

Comment: This is a great first question on SO, Andrea C Bauer! For faster, demonstrably _verified_ answers, it is best to include sample data as well. The gold standard is to paste the output from `dput(head(x, 20))` where `x` is your frame (for each, if multiple), and `20` is a number that sufficiently supports your question without having to give us _everything_. (Also, removing unused columns is much appreciated, too.) See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for good discussions/demonstrations of this. Thanks!

Comment: Why use facets at all? Your problems will essentially be solved by simply removing the facets.

Comment: Good point @AllanCameron. AndreaCBauer, if my current answer/suggestions don't work for you, you will need to provide sample data as suggested above. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. It really helped.Should I edit my question to add my dataframe?

Comment: – r2evans, you are right. "One tweak, since I find your long Microorganism names may be a pain.....". But I really would like to use facet_grid instead of facet_wrap. Do you know how I can fit the big text (names of the microorganisms) in 2 lines in  each  label Y

Comment: Hi, one more help. I have 24 studies, so I need 24 colors. Some studies are without color in the graph. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gridlines can be removed with `theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())`, possibly `panel.grid.major=` as well or just `panel.grid=`. See [`?theme`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html), namely:

```
panel.grid, panel.grid.major, panel.grid.minor, panel.grid.major.x,
          panel.grid.major.y, panel.grid.minor.x, panel.grid.minor.y:
          grid lines (element_line()). Specify major grid lines, or
          minor grid lines separately (using ‘panel.grid.major’ or
          ‘panel.grid.minor’) or individually for each axis (using
          ‘panel.grid.major.x’, ‘panel.grid.minor.x’,
          ‘panel.grid.major.y’, ‘panel.grid.minor.y’).  Y axis grid
          lines are horizontal and x axis grid lines are vertical.
          panel.grid.*.* inherits from panel.grid.* which inherits from
          ‘panel.grid’, which in turn inherits from ‘line’
```

Switch facet strips from right to left is handled with `facet_grid(..., switch=""y")`. See [`?facet_grid`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html), namely

```
  switch: By default, the labels are displayed on the top and right of
          the plot. If ‘"x"’, the top labels will be displayed to the
          bottom. If ‘"y"’, the right-hand side labels will be
          displayed to the left. Can also be set to ‘"both"’.
```

For "centering" the bubbles, it's really hard without sample data, but I suspect you can use `scales="free_y"`.

Perhaps this:

```r
graph <- ggplot(patog1, aes(x = Prevalence, y = Microorganism)) +
  geom_point(data=patog1,aes(x=JitCoOr, y=JitCoOrPow,size = Samples, colour = Study), alpha=.5)+
  geom_text(data=patog1,aes(x=JitCoOr, y=JitCoOrPow,label=Samples)) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1,30))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(10))+ 
  facet_grid(Microorganism~., scales = "free_y", switch = "y")+
  theme_bw()
graph +
  theme(
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

---

***Update*** with sample data.

We can add `scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = 1.5))` to expand the y-axis a bit. The 1.5 is subjective, over to you. (There's also the `add=` argument, see `?expansion` for details.)

One tweak, since I find your long `Microorganism` names may be a pain: I'm switching from `facet_grid` to `facet_wrap(..., ncol = 1)`, which means we need to remove `switch=` and instead use `strip.position="top"`. It's just a suggestion, take it or leave it.

Another tweak, though the effective change is only efficiency and code-golf: since you specify `data=patog1` in the call to `ggplot(.)` and use the same `data=patog1` in the `geom_*` calls, you can remove the `geom`-data calls, they will use the same data.

```r
ggplot(patog1, aes(x = Prevalence, y = Microorganism)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = JitCoOr, y = JitCoOrPow, size = Samples, colour = Study), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = JitCoOr, y = JitCoOrPow, label = Samples)) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 30)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = 1.5)) + 
  facet_wrap(Microorganism ~ ., ncol = 1, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "top") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

[image: ggplot with centered bubbles]

Since you really want to use `facet_grid`, I think it can't work *well* without either (a) substantially shrinking the font, or (b) replace spaces with newlines. I'll demo #2:

```r
transform(patog1, Microorganism = gsub(" ", "\n", Microorganism)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Prevalence, y = Microorganism)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = JitCoOr, y = JitCoOrPow, size = Samples, colour = Study), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = JitCoOr, y = JitCoOrPow, label = Samples)) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 30)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = 1.5)) + 
  facet_grid(Microorganism ~ ., scales = "free_y", switch = "y") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  )
```

(and a slightly taller graphics window)

[image: same graphic, using facet_grid]

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. It really helped. Should I edit my question to add my data frame?

Comment: See my edit @AndreaCBauer, hope it helps.

Comment: One more question: you are right. " long Microorganism names may be a pain.....". But I really would like to use facet_grid instead of facet_wrap. Do you know how I can fit the big text (names of the microorganisms) in 2 lines on each label Y

Comment: Sure, see my edit.

Comment: Hi, one more help. I have 24 studies, so I need 24 colors. Some studies are without color in the graph. Thanks

Comment: If you're talking about those with `Samples` like 59 where there is no apparent circle ... the colored circles are indeed there, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeJws.png. You have a problem with _scale_, meaning your larger values scale-out the smaller values. You can try adding a transform to the size, starting with something like `scale_size_continuous(trans = "log10")`, which is intended to normalize it a little. The `59`s are still not obvious, but perhaps you need to use `size=pmax(150, Samples)` or some other "trick", though that biases the visual correlation of size (as does `"log10"`).